# "of" or "in" in this situation

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am applying for a degree in a university.

they ask me to send them a recommendation letter from one of my professor.

I want to write the position of this professor.

I write this:

> Doctor **of** Software Engineering. Also, He was the dean of faculty of Information Technology Engineering

Is it correct to use "of" or it would be better to use "in" or what please?

Comment: Your use of **of** is precisely correct. However, if he is still *Dean of Faculty* (use caps), use the present tense; if not, refer to him as former D of F. Finally, if Information Technology is a school, you can say *at* (or just a comma) *D of F, ITE; if it's a department, it should be *D of F, Dept. of ITE, (university/other)

Comment: @Susan what do mean by "use caps" ?. what do you mean by D or F?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! Use capital letters for titles, and *D of F* is an abbreviation for *Dean of Faculty.*

Comment: @Susan do you mean that I have to write `DEAN OF FACULTY` ? please

Comment: I must apologize again. No, not all capitals (caps). Just the first letters of the title (excluding the preposition). Dean of Faculty. Dean of Georgetown College. Assistant Dean and Director of Pre-Health Programs.

Comment: @Susan now I got you, thank you, write an answer to accept it please. Also would you check this question too http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15077/what-is-the-correct-grammar-for-this-sentence

Comment: Sorry, but one doesn't apply to a university for a degree. One applies to a university to study for or earn a degree. **PhD in software engineering** That's enough. No need to write it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of **of** is precisely correct. However, if he is still Dean of Faculty (D o F), use the present tense; if not, refer to him as former D of F. Finally, if Information Technology Engineering (ITE) is a school, you can say "at" (or just a comma) *D of F, ITE*; if it's a department, it should be *D of F, Dept. of ITE, (university/other)*

Capitalize the first letters of a title (excluding the preposition), e.g. Dean of Faculty, Dean of Georgetown College, Assistant Dean and Director of Pre-Health Programs.

Comment: because he is not the dean now, if i understand you answer correctly, i will write this `Doctor of Software Engineering. Also, He is former Dean of Faculty of Information Technology Engineering` , is that correct ?

Comment: @user3110137 - yes, that is correct. :-)

Comment: sorry, just one last question, would it be better if i used `a` before `former`. like this `he is a former...` ?

Comment: No. If you are using a descriptive, use **the** former.